# Fix function error with a component in reactjs library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a library in reactjs name: React-fileupload-progress,
so, it has a component name

```
<FileUploadProgress key='ex1' 
    url={this.props.url+this.state.nameDocument}
    onProgress={this.onProgress}
    onLoad={this.onLoaded}
    onError={this.onError}
    onAbort={ (e, request) => {console.log('abort', e, request);}}
    beforeSend={this.beforeSend}
/>
```

So, this component will send a request to URL,
before send request, it will run function `beforeSend`, `beforeSend` helps me adjust data before send, will return a request, then, it send request to URL and response will return in 3 function (`onLoad`, `onError`, `onAbort`). But, when I use before send, I detect an error and I want to it stop send request but it doesn't. In console, it show

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
>     at FileUploadProgress._doUpload

So, I don't know how to fix it.
Here are props of this component:

```
FileUploadProgress.propTypes = {
    url: _propTypes2.default.string.isRequired,
    formGetter: _propTypes2.default.func,
    formRenderer: _propTypes2.default.func,
    progressRenderer: _propTypes2.default.func,
    formCustomizer: _propTypes2.default.func,
    beforeSend: _propTypes2.default.func,
    onProgress: _propTypes2.default.func,
    onLoad: _propTypes2.default.func,
    onError: _propTypes2.default.func,
    onAbort: _propTypes2.default.func
};
```

Comment: What is this line `onError={this.onError}_doUpload` ?

Comment: oh, thank, i edited

Comment: I had a right. At the end of the beforeSend, i add: return {...request, send: function(){}}. So, it was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a right. At the end of the beforeSend, i add:

```
return {
...request, 
send: function(){}
}
```

So, it was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeSend: (req)=>{ this.beforeSend();return req;}
```

beforeSend should return as Reqeust